# Scala, cannot avoid cyclic parametrization

Tags: scala, types

I have reduced my problem to the MWE (minimum (non)-working example). Here it goes:

First, we have a datatype `Loss`, which is essentially a `Function2` and thus contravariant in T.

```
abstract class Loss[-T] {
    def apply(actual: T, predicted: T): Double
}
```

Next, we have a Labeled, of which loss is the property:

```
abstract class Labeled[+T <: Labeled[T]] {
    def loss[Q >: T]: Loss[Q]
}
```

It is also naturally covariant and it has to be F-bounded. Up to this point, the program compiles. The problem arises when I want to make a concrete case class implementation of the `Labeled` abstract class. I have tried this:

```
Error:(9, 12) class Numerical needs to be abstract, since method loss in class Labeled of type [Q >: Numerical]=> Loss[Q] is not defined
case class Numerical(name: Symbol, loss: Loss[_ >: Numerical]) extends Labeled[Numerical] {
           ^
```

However I try to parametrize it, I get to a cyclic definition. How could this be done, or if not, tell me what I am thinking wrong.

How I have gotten to work **(warning: bad hack):** I have removed abstract specification of `loss` from `Labeled` and just kept the above definition in all subclasses. When I need to call `loss` on a general `Labeled` class, I pattern match for every possible subclass. I hope this gets solved someday.

Comment: There is a contradiction. You tried to override method `loss` with value `loss`. But method can have type parameter (and adjust actual type every time it is called) and value can not - it has statically defined type

Comment: In scala, you can override a method with a value, right? What I want to achieve is to be able to pass arbitrary loss of [Q >: T] to Labeled[T] or its case class.

Comment: Not a parameterized method.

Comment: I want to consctruct a case class that extends Labeled[T] with an arbitrary Loss[Q >: T]. How to do that, then?

For example: Numerical('test, x: Loss[NumericalSuperclass])

Comment: `def loss : Loss[Q] forSome { type Q >: T }`

Comment: `Error:(24, 6) covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type => qlearn.loss.Loss[_ >: T] of method loss`

Comment: Everyting compiles OK, if I remove loss signature from Labeled. But I need it there, because I need to make general enough calls.

Comment: I used to trust the compiler in variance checking. If it says that some is contravariant than it is. And you should either switch to invariant definition or sacrifice some functionality. If that was in my code, I have tried to avoid simple case class declaration with custom one

Comment: Have you tried just to discard precise type and just use AnyRef?  Akka actors works in this way

Comment: It is not clear why you say `Labeled` is *naturally covariant*. What use case do you have in mind?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Labeled is naturally covariant, that means that you can pass Labeled[Binary] as Labeled[Discrete] anywhere, as Binary is just a special case (subclass) of Discrete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it said in comments you can't override *parametrized* method with value, so you probably have to move `Q` out of `loss`'s definition:

```
abstract class Labeled[+T <: Labeled[T]] {
    type TT <: T
    type Q >: TT

    def loss: Loss[Q]
}

case class Numerical(name: Symbol, loss: Loss[Numerical#Q]) extends Labeled[Numerical]
```

You may want to specify Q itself (existential type `_ >: Numerical`, represented with `Q >: TT` here, will resolve to `Any` otherwise):

```
 case class Numerical(name: Symbol, loss: Loss[Numerical#Q]) extends Labeled[Numerical] {
   type Q = Numerical //can only be >: than Numerical
 }
```

So now you can use it:

```
 scala> :paste
 // Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

 Numerical('a, new Loss[Numerical#Q] {
   def apply(actual: Numerical#Q, predicted: Numerical#Q): Double = {
     actual.loss //check that it's available, as you put `Q = Numeric`
     0L
   }
 })

 // Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

 res19: Numerical = Numerical('a,$anon$1@6355264c)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make it work. Do you, by any chance have any good resource that would cover advanced scala type system features?